Thunderbird AddOn for text replacement debugging
this is my first TB addOn development and I need a hint for debugging. The addOn is a kind of auto correction or auto text replacement. This means, you can save a shortcut like 'br' and it will replaced with 'Br, John Doe'. This works automaticly and to this point everythings works fine.
But I would like to offer in setup the function to replace the shortcut if Enter-Key is pressed only. And here I have the problem, the cursor position, if enterReplace is active, aint got catched correctly and the replacement failed. I tried a lot, to asked ChatGPT was aint helpful as well.
This is the Code:
window.addEventListener("keydown", async (event) => {
    // Retrieve settings from local storage
    let setting_enter = await browser.storage.local.get({ enterReplace: false });

    // Get the current cursor position node
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    let node = range.startContainer;

    // Only handle text nodes if Enter was not pressed
    if (node.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE && event.code !== 'Enter') {
        return;
    }

    // Function for text replacement and HTML insertion
    const replaceText = async () => {
        console.log("Node text content:", node.textContent); // Debugging
        console.log("Cursor position (offset):", range.startOffset); // Debugging

        // Get text up to the cursor position in the current node
        let textBeforeCursor = node.textContent.slice(0, range.startOffset);
        console.log("Text before cursor:", textBeforeCursor); // Debugging

        // Capture the last word before the cursor
        let words = textBeforeCursor.trim().split(/\s+/); // Split the text into words
        let wordToReplace = words[words.length - 1]; // The last word is what we want to replace

        console.log("Word to replace:", wordToReplace); // Debugging

        // Retrieve replacements from storage
        let data = await browser.storage.local.get({ replacements: [] });
        let replacements = data.replacements;

        // Check if the last word is a shortcut and should be replaced
        let shortcutFound = false; // Variable to determine if a shortcut was found
        for (let item of replacements) {
            console.log("Checking shortcut:", item.shortcut); // Debugging
            if (wordToReplace === item.shortcut) {
                shortcutFound = true; // Shortcut found
                // Replace line breaks with <br> for HTML context
                let replacementText = item.replacement.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

                // Replace text in the range
                let newText = textBeforeCursor.slice(0, -wordToReplace.length);

                // Remove old text up to the shortcut
                range.setStart(node, newText.length);
                range.setEnd(node, textBeforeCursor.length);
                range.deleteContents();

                // Insert HTML by creating a new Range object
                let fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(replacementText);
                range.insertNode(fragment);

                // After inserting, set the cursor to the end of the inserted HTML
                range.collapse(false);
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range);
                break; // Break the loop after replacing the shortcut
            }
        }

        // If no shortcut was found, we can log a message here
        if (!shortcutFound) {
            console.log("No matching shortcut found for:", wordToReplace);
        }
    };

    // If 'enterReplace' is active and Enter is pressed
    if (setting_enter.enterReplace && event.code === 'Enter') {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default Enter key effect

        // Handle replacement and cursor position in one step
        await replaceText();

        // Optionally: add a new line break after the replacement is done
        let brNode = document.createElement("br");
        range.insertNode(brNode);
        range.collapse(false);  // Set the cursor to the end
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    } else if (!setting_enter.enterReplace) {
        // Apply delay only if 'enterReplace' is not active
        setTimeout(async () => {
            // Recheck the current selection
            selection = window.getSelection();
            range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
            node = range.startContainer;

            await replaceText();
        }, 700);
    }
}); 

Where is the bug?
Thx!
autoReplace Setup
